# How to filter posts by specific date and its tag

Tags: tags, meta-query

I want to show the post dates of posts which is greater than `$postdate` value.
what is the wrong with the following code?

Instead of filtering the data by dates, it shows all the dates. I do not know what the problem is with the logic.

Any help will be most appreciated.

```
$postdate =  get_the_date('Y-m-d');
$update = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'post_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC' ,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'post_date',
            'compare' => '>',
            'value' => $postdate,
            'type' => 'numeric'
        )
    )    
));

while ($update->have_posts()) {
    $update->the_post(); ?>
        <p class="center">
            <span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();  ?></a></span><br>
            <span class="small"><i><?php  the_date();  ?></i></span>
        </p><?php
} ?>
```

Comment: there's a missing quote on the word key that might be generating a syntax error, I don't know that it will get you the posts you want, but without that `'` you'll get a screen of death for invalid PHP code

Comment: Thank you but i added the quote still i canot see any result

Comment: what are the contents of your custom fields 'post_date'?

Comment: you can't see any result is interpreted as you don't see the posts, but do you really mean you see nothing at all?  Aka a white screen of death? Or the page just stops at  the point it reaches your code and nothing comes after it?

Comment: Also, what's the plugin you mentioned that supports PHP codes for custom HTML? Can you edit your question so the code is how it is locally? The `'` is still missing so the code in your question would generate PHP fatal syntax errors, and it breaks the syntax highlighting. Also update the question to explain where and how this code is being ran

Comment: Dear Tom J Nowell, I installed advanced cutom field plugin and created a custom field for all posts named post_date. now it shows the posts on the front page. but it canot filter the data by the specific date '$postdate'!  i want to filter posts by their tags as well. any solution, Thanks

Comment: The plugin that i am using is named PHP Code

Answer (score 3):

Ashur

Please try following code with [date_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters). this is working fine at my end.
Let me know if you want any additional detail.

```
<?php
$postdate = get_the_date('Y-m-d');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => $postdate,
    )
);
$update = new WP_Query($args);

while ($update->have_posts()) {
    $update->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $post_title = get_the_title();
    $post_date = get_the_date();
    $post_link = get_the_permalink();
    ?>
    <p class="center">
        <span><a href="<?php echo $post_link; ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></span><br>
        <span class="small"><i><?php echo $post_date; ?></i></span>
    </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This solution is useful for you? if not than ping me I will give you another one.

Comment: Thank you Dip Patel

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer then please upvote me & correct my answer.Thanks.